# Doctrine - return recent date by user

Tags: php, doctrine, query-builder

I am trying to write a query which will return one result (one date) from a user, more precisely his latest date from database.

I think I am on a good path because I get ID from that user but I can't figure out how to generate most recent date added to database by that user?

Any ideas?

My code:

```
 $user = $transaction[0]->getAccount()->getUser()->getId();

    $query = $this->getTransactionRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t')
        ->where('t.account = :account')
        ->setParameter('account' , $user)
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->orderBy('t.date', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    dump($query);die;
```